# Jasper subdataset parameter incrementing unexpectedly

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper report with a Pie Chart that is being drawn at the group_footer for my group "contract".  The contract group is returning two rows at this time and I am using the contract id which are integers 1 and 3. When I print the contract id in the group_footer, it prints 1 and then 3 as expected.  However, when I try and pass the same contract id into a datasetrun for the Pie Chart in the very same group_footer, the value being passed into the parameter is 3 for both charts (I am viewing the SQL using statement logging on the db server). I can not figure out how it's sending the second value "3" both times. As I mentioned, the contract id prints on the report right next to the chart as "1" the first item in the group.

Here is my subDataset with the parameter "currentContractId":

```
<subDataset name="age_stats" uuid="44847f01-474b-4228-96e9-ea5ab992f67b">
  <property name="....data.defaultdataadapter" value="database"/>
  <parameter name="currentContractId" class="...Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
  <queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = $P{currentContractId}]]>
  </queryString>
  <field name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
</subDataset>
```

Here is the chart datasetrun where I am trying to pass the field "id" into the "currentContractId" parameter for my subDataset above:

```
<pieDataset maxCount="6">
  <dataset>
    <datasetRun subDataset="age_stats" uuid="75d14f7c-f94e-4749-860f-ea95c2134e9c">
      <datasetParameter name="currentContractId">
        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
      </datasetParameter>
    </datasetRun>
  </dataset>
</pieDataset>
```

I am happy to provide the full jrxml to anyone who thinks it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.  Aside from the options in the chart dataset wizard, there is a seperate option under the chart properties called "Evaluation Time". I set the Evaluation Time option to my Group "contract" and the problem was resolved.